# Magical $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$-square

Tags: co.combinatorics, recreational-mathematics

**Now duplicate of [Magic $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$-square](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/344011/) where it has an answer.**

---

Is there an injective map $j:\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ satisfying: For every $z\in \mathbb{Z}$ we have $$\lim_{N\to \infty}\sum_{k=-N}^Nj(k,z) = 0 = \lim_{N\to \infty}\sum_{k=-N}^Nj(z,k)\text{ ?}$$

That is, for every $z\in \mathbb{Z}$ there is $N_0=N_0(z)\in \mathbb{N}$, such that for every integer $N\geq N_0$ we have 
$$\sum_{k=-N}^Nj(k,z) = 0 = \sum_{k=-N}^Nj(z,k).$$

---

**Note.** 
Martin Sleziak has answered this question in another thread: https://mathoverflow.net/a/344049/8628 (no answers could be posted here since this question is on hold).

Comment: I am not sure why this problem was down-voted or why it was put on hold.  There is at least one paper in the literature on infinite magic squares (different from this generalization): Antoine Salomon, "Infinite sized magic square," the American Mathematical Monthly (January 2014). https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01401844v4/document      There is also a discussion elsewhere on this site about infinite magic squares. 
  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/53420/magic-square-on-an-infinite-lattice  If this problem is somehow trivial, then someone can provide the solution.

Comment: Thanks @Tri! Seeing the downvotes, I assumed there must be a trivial answer to my question - but please can anyone give a hint to a trivial example or a trivial reason why such a $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$-square can not exist?

Comment: One problem is that these limits are never defined, since the summands are distinct integers.

Comment: @BenBarber If $s: \mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{Z}$ is a sequence of integers, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} s(n) = 0$ iff there is $K\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $s(n) = 0$ for all $n\geq K$, or am I mistaken? - At all events, I have provided an alternative formulation of the question that tries to avoid the problem that Ben Barber mentions. Are there any other problems / ambiguities in the question?

Comment: @BenBarber The limits may be defined if for each $z_0$ there is some $N_{z_0}$ such that for $n > N_{z_0}$, $j(n, z_0) + j(-n, z_0) = 0$ (and similar for the other argument), since the limits are of the symmetric sums.

Comment: Right @user44191 - because of this symmetry I am inclined to believe that such magical squares cannot exist, but maybe "weakly magical ones": https://mathoverflow.net/questions/344011/weakly-magic-mathbbz-times-mathbbz-square

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that that was a rather careless comment.  Your observations have brought me round to thinking you should be able to just do this: fill in the lines $y=0, x=0, y=1, x=1, y=-1, \ldots$ in order so that (i) they sum to $0$ and have the "eventually paired" property to ensure convergence (ii) the entries are chosen from a very sparse subset of $\mathbb Z$ and (iii) you make sure to use the numbers of absolute value at most $n$ by the end of the $n$th stage.  I think these are all easy to ensure.

Comment: (iii) isn't necessary if you don't want a bijection.  This seems to be one of those cases where making the problem infinite removes a lot of potential difficulties: it's much easier to get stuck in a finite world.

Comment: Thanks @BenBarber - I asked the weaker question (which I will remove once I am convinced there is a positive answer to this question) because I felt pretty sure that this question has a negative answer due to the symmetry condition that user44191 described above. But I think your line of thinking might be a path forward. Can you elaborate it into an answer?

Comment: Martin Sleziak has answered this question in another thread: https://mathoverflow.net/a/344049/8628 (because this question here is locked, no anwers could be posted).

Comment: @DominicvanderZypen I've copied the question here to the other thread. I suggest you delete this one since it doesn't need to be in 2 threads. (For memory, the question was initially downvoted and closed because the sum was not specified to be from $-N$ to $+N$, so the convergence was obviously impossible).